# "This message was added in version X" showing a later version than current one

Tags: wpdb, errors

An error message is displayed :

> The query does not contain the correct number of placeholders (1) for
>   the number of arguments passed (2). This message was added in version
>   **4.8.3**.

Problem: I am using Wordpress **4.3.22** .

Anybody has an explanation?

NB: that message is coming from `wpdb::prepare`.

Comment: This may as well be version of some plugin.

Comment: No it's not, as it's coming from `wpdb::prepare`. It's strictly hard-written "4.8.3" in the 4.3.22 version of `wp-db.php`.

Comment: WordPress 4.3 is 5 years old. You really should not be using a version that old.

Comment: @JacobPeattie WP 4.3.22 is 1 year old.

Comment: A minor security patch is. You should not be 8 major versions behind.

Comment: Why? I can't tell my client "I'm going to upgrade to the latest major version, and I'll have to change all my 5 years old developments according to this. Note: it's gonna take a week and it will bring you nothing."

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is some hasty copy/paste mistake in WP code while backporting features/bugfixes to older versions. Checked 4.3.22 code - it indeed contains version number 4.8.3 attached to this error message.

Comment: It also contains 4.9.0 (same method) and so on. I don't think it's a copy/paste mistake.

Comment: Or it's a big big one.

Comment: Does this really changes something for you? There is nothing big here. Just rational software development process. Feature from newer version was backported to older version. They could change version numbers to reflect older version, but that would require additional work without any benefits. You can read it as "this message was added in version 4.8.3, but it was later backported to version 4.3.22". If you need more info, study this commit https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/commit/8227bf664fc38f270834619666775fac9d901e64

Comment: Yes it does, it's making my WPML plugin buggy.

Comment: What's more, it's strange that a minor update makes major feature changes. Backwards compatibility should be reliable for minor updates.

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger. :) Those changes in wp-db.php were made in 2017 and '4.8.3' code is in WP versions starting 4.3.13. Your problem is somewhere else. Maybe changelog helps - https://wordpress.org/support/wordpress-version/version-4-3-22/

Comment: It's not against you, more against a development policy that I really don't get